# How to add loading circle animation to image in recycerview before load android

Tags: android

I am a new application developer. I use recycerview  to display a set of images to the user.What I want to do now if the image is still not shown to the user, it shows in each image a circular effect.I sorry for that. This question may have been asked a lot time before now, but I could not find an answer to my question.

What I need to do like the following picture:
[image]

How I can do that ?

MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<List_Data>list_data;
    Context ct;




    public MyAdapter(List<List_Data> list_data, Context ct) {
        this.list_data = list_data;
        this.ct = ct;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_data,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final List_Data listData=list_data.get(position);
        Picasso.with(ct)
                .load(listData.getImageurl())
                .into(holder.img);



    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list_data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ImageView img;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
 private static final String HI = "https://uniqueandrocode.000webhostapp.com/hiren/androidtutorial/androidweb.php";
    private List<List_Data> list_data;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private JsonArrayRequest request;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        list_data=new ArrayList<>();


        getImageData();
    }

    private void getImageData() {
        request=new JsonArrayRequest(HI, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                for (int i=0; i<response.length(); i++){
                    try {
                        jsonObject=response.getJSONObject(i);
                        List_Data listData=new List_Data(jsonObject.getString("imageurl"));
                        list_data.add(listData);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                setupData(list_data);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);

    }

    private void setupData(List<List_Data> list_data) {
        adapter=new MyAdapter(list_data,this);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are required to add a progress bar on the top of the RecylerView item layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now inside your **RecyclerViewAdapter's `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)`**  method.

Add this code:

```
holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Change this code:

```
Picasso.with(ct)
    .load(listData.getImageurl())
    .into(holder.img);
```

To:

```
Picasso.with(ct)
    .load(listData.getImageurl())
    .into(holder.img, new Callback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
 
                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
```

And also update your ViewHolder Too.

Comment: Hello brother, thank you for your response. The method works for me, but this is the usual effect that people are used to seeing in all the application, but if you look at the image of the example that I uploaded in my question a little bit different so that it covers all the image

Comment: @Mafo I have updated the answer please check if it solves your problem.